# Labeling GeoJSON Polygon in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I cannot find anywhere in the Mapbox GL JS documentation on how to add a simple label to a GeoJSON polygon so I am working off of a few examples I have found.

My GeoJSON is structured like so:

```
const gj = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "id": "309"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              77.34374999999999,
              54.57206165565852
            ],
            [
              124.45312499999999,
              63.074865690586634
            ],
            [
              102.65625,
              64.16810689799152
            ],
            [
              77.34374999999999,
              54.57206165565852
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
         "id": "310"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              81.9140625,
              48.22467264956519
            ],
            [
              124.45312499999999,
              51.39920565355378
            ],
            [
              122.6953125,
              59.88893689676585
            ],
            [
              81.9140625,
              48.22467264956519
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to label the polygons with the `id` field.

Here is what that looks like:

```
map.addSource("maine", {
            type: "geojson",
            data: gj,
          });
          map.addLayer({
            id: "maine",
            type: "fill",
            source: "maine",
            layout: {
              "text-field": ['get','id'],
            },
            paint: {
              "fill-color": "#088",
              "fill-opacity": 0.8,
            },
          });
```

The issue I'm having is that when I add the `text-field` to the `layout` object, the layer doesn't render at all. I've searched Mapbox's docs and on here as well, but I cannot find a vanilla way to add a simple label.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that, if you are trying to add labels to polygons using this library, you first need to create a point layer from the existing data set and use that to label.

This website helped me figure it out: http://fuzzytolerance.info/blog/2016/07/15/Generate-centroid-points-from-polygons-with-Turf-js/